# Decrypt AES encrypted text from javascript using PHP

Tags: php

**strong text**I have encrypted some text using CryptoJs, javascript. Now I want to decrypt it using PHP.

My **encrypted** string from js is this.

> **U2FsdGVkX1+xxsL9T2PF8RaVBYK27yaishU0qa8lJXPuKj82S6jbmW8phxhl1FwT**

And **js code** is as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
        var data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]

        // Encrypt
        var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), 'salyno1');

        console.log(ciphertext.toString());



    })
```

Now in **php** i tried

```
<?php

$decrypted = simple_decrypt("U2FsdGVkX1+xxsL9T2PF8RaVBYK27yaishU0qa8lJXPuKj82S6jbmW8phxhl1FwT", 'salyno1');

echo($decrypted);
function simple_decrypt($encrypted, $salt)  {
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, pack('H*', $salt), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size=mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND)));
}
?>
```

But I am getting **error** as below :

> Warning: pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit s in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\publications\api\encryption.php on line 7

I am absolutely new to this, need some help in startup.

I am also trying some other things, if it works.

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: The "encrypted string from js" is Base64 encoded, not hex encoded. Suggestion:Take the time to learn hex and Base64 encoding. `pack('H*'` is specifying hex but the data is not hex. See [PHP pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php).